# Shadcn trigger opening incorrect content in React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, tailwind-css

first time posting and I have a question. So I am using Shadcn and create a page.tsx element that is based on Shadcn/ui's Sheet component so it can be reused with the exact styling i want across my app. I set it up using props initially and it worked exactlys as I wanted, but it was verbose and annoying to use so I pivoted to child components, but now when I click on a trigger, it always opens up the content of the last item each section rather than that triggers corresponding content. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

import { Media, MediaContextProvider } from '~/lib/fresnel';

import { ChevronLeftIcon } from './icons/ChevronLeftIcon';
import {
  Sheet,
  SheetContent,
  SheetDescription,
  SheetHeader,
  SheetTitle,
  SheetTrigger,
} from './Sheet';

const DIV_CLASSNAME = '-m-6 bg-white px-6 py-3';

interface SubSheetItemProps {
  trigger: string;
  children: JSX.Element[];
}

const SubSheetItem: React.FC<SubSheetItemProps> = ({ trigger, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SheetTrigger>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <span>{trigger}</span>
          <ChevronLeftIcon className="rotate-180" />
        </div>
      </SheetTrigger>
      <SheetContent className={twMerge('bg-slate-100')}>
        <SheetHeader>
          <div className={twMerge(DIV_CLASSNAME, 'mb-px')}>
            <SheetTitle className="text-center text-xl">{trigger}</SheetTitle>
          </div>
          <div className={DIV_CLASSNAME}>
            <SheetDescription>{children}</SheetDescription>
          </div>
        </SheetHeader>
      </SheetContent>
    </>
  );
};

interface SubSheetProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<SubSheetItemProps>[];
}

const SubSheet: React.FC<SubSheetProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Sheet>
      <SheetHeader className="py-1">
        {React.Children.map(children, (child) => (
          <React.Fragment key={child.props.trigger}>{child}</React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </SheetHeader>
    </Sheet>
  );
};

interface SectionProps {
  title: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Section: React.FC<SectionProps> = ({ title, children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={twMerge(DIV_CLASSNAME)}>
      <SheetTitle>{title}</SheetTitle>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

interface PageProps {
  title: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Page: React.FC<PageProps> & {
  Section: typeof Section;
  SubSheet: typeof SubSheet;
  SubSheetItem: typeof SubSheetItem;
} = ({ title, children }) => {
  return (
    <MediaContextProvider>
      <Media greaterThanOrEqual="sm">
        <SheetContent className="w-96 bg-slate-100">
          <SheetHeader>
            <div className={DIV_CLASSNAME}>
              <SheetTitle className="text-center text-xl">{title}</SheetTitle>
            </div>
            <br />
            {children}
          </SheetHeader>
        </SheetContent>
      </Media>
      <Media lessThan="sm">
        <SheetContent size="full" className="bg-slate-100">
          <SheetHeader>
            <div className={DIV_CLASSNAME}>
              <SheetTitle className="text-center text-xl">{title}</SheetTitle>
            </div>
            <br />
            {children}
          </SheetHeader>
        </SheetContent>
      </Media>
    </MediaContextProvider>
  );
};

Page.Section = Section;
Page.SubSheet = SubSheet;
Page.SubSheetItem = SubSheetItem;

export default Page;
```

and here is a use case:

```
<Page title={t('settings.title')}>
      <Page.Section title="App Preferences">
        <LanguageDropdown />
        <br></br>
        <MapStyleDropdown />
      </Page.Section>

      <Page.Section title="Policy">
        <Page.SubSheet>
          <Page.SubSheetItem trigger="Test2345">
            <LanguageDropdown />
            <br />
          </Page.SubSheetItem>
          <Page.SubSheetItem trigger="Test">
            <LanguageDropdown />
            <br />
          </Page.SubSheetItem>
        </Page.SubSheet>
      </Page.Section>

      <Page.Section title="Terms">
        <Page.SubSheet>
          <Page.SubSheetItem trigger="Policy">
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test2</p>
          </Page.SubSheetItem>
          <Page.SubSheetItem trigger="Policy2">
            <p>test2</p>
            <p>test</p>
          </Page.SubSheetItem>
        </Page.SubSheet>
      </Page.Section>
    </Page>
```

so in this example if I click on trigger called Test2345, it opens up the content within trigger="Test" and same for Page.section title=terms, when I click the trigger with           <Page.SubSheetItem trigger="Policy"> it opens up the content of trigger policy2

Thank you for any help in advance!

I tried using use states and that didnt work for me so maybe someone else has some better ideas

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).